# Leaflet Map is Zooming out too far

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet

Using NodeJS to drop datapoints on a map via Leaflet.

**Current issue:**

When I scroll out, I can't get the map region to be locked to one Earth. That is, when I scroll out all the way, I end up with 5 copies of Earth, unique from each other. I want the map to be locked to one frame of the Earth.

**Methods tried:**

I've tried using Map.setView, setZoom, fitBounds, setMaxBounds/maxBounds (which was successful in locking panning, but not scrolling). As far as I can tell I've been using these correctly/in the correct places, but still to no avail.

Comment: put some code...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out [Eugen!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2951933/eugen-sunic)

Needs to be set in the initializeLeaflet method. Code added to fix it seen at the bottom of this block.

```
initializeLeaflet() {
        const mapRoot = this.template.querySelector('.map-root');
        this.map = L.map(mapRoot);
        this.map.fitWorld();
        L.control.scale().addTo(this.map);
        this.map.setMinZoom(2);
        this.map.setMaxZoom(8);
    }
```